# ImportError: No module named bluetooth after update python 2.7.3 -> 2.7.9

Tags: python

i update python from 2.7.3 to 2.7.9 in raspberry ..

first i download source from python.org and `configure & make & make install`

no when i command python in terminal python 2.7.9 executed ...

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan 27 2015, 21:20:44)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

but all module that i installed from `apt-get install` is now unknown ...

like `sudo apt-get install python-bluez`

how can i fix it ?

Comment: Why did you install Python modules via `apt-get` and not via `pip`?

Comment: because apt-get is simpler than pip :D ... now i reinstall module via pip ?

Comment: 0_o How is `apt-get` simpler than `pip`?